# .load with jsTree

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jstree

I'm helping a friend try to set up jsTree. We are trying to make it so when a node is clicked, a page is loaded in another div off to the side. However, everything seems to be working, but the `.load` does not fire for some reason. I used alert to check `thisItem` and it is defined and is the correct variable.

```
$(function() {

    $('.tree').jstree().delegate("a", "click", function(event, data){
        event.preventDefault();
        var thisItem = $(this).attr('id');
        thisItem += ".html";
        alert(thisItem);
        $('.table').load(thisItem);
        });

});
```

This is the HTML:

```
<div class = "tree">  
    <ul>
    <li id = "1"><a href = "" id = "1">Test 1</a>
        <ul>
        <li id = "2"><a href = "" id = "2">Test 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class = "table">
</div>
```

I have pages that will correspond to these ids that I want to load into `table`. This works without the jstree with a regular `.click`...but I'd like to use it with jstree.

I just can't figure out why it won't load the page when using jstree...but it will work when I don't use jstree. I even tried doing a `.click` on `.tree li` outside of the jstree stuff but that didn't work either. (If I get rid of the jstree stuff all together this code here works.)

```
$('.tree li').click(function() {
        var thisItem = $(this).attr('id');
        thisItem += ".html";
        $('.table').load(thisItem);
    });
```

Note: This is just a test for a more dynamic piece of a project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can execute your own code by binding custom events (`some-event.jstree`) to the jstree element, the one you're looking for in this case is `select_node.jstree`:

```
$('.tree').bind("select_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
   var $obj = data.rslt.obj; // this will be a jquery object representing the <li> you've clicked
   var url = $obj.attr("id") + ".html";
   $('.table').load(url);
});
```

Info about the `data` object passed to the callback function (from the [jstree documentation](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/core#)):

```
{
   "inst" : /* the actual tree instance */,
   "args" : /* arguments passed to the function */,
   "rslt" : /* any data the function passed to the event */,
   "rlbk" : /* an optional rollback object - it is not always present */
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the first demo here: http://www.jstree.com/documentation/core#demos

Your click handler doesn't work as I believe the plugin itself unbinds click handlers as they use their own custom events.  You can bind into these events via the same methodology they do in the first demo.

```
$("#demo1").jstree("toggle_node","#phtml_1");
$("#demo1").bind("open_node.jstree close_node.jstree", function (e) {
    //Stuff
});
```

The events appear to follow the form "*function*.jstree".  So the `open_node.jstree` event is fired after the `open_node` function occurs.  You can find the function list on the same link above.